# iOS7 specific bug (page does not load, works fine in iOS8)

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm building a mobile-optimized website via Shopify. There is an iOS7 specific bug and I have no idea why

The private beta can be found at cobblerconciergevip.com

The user clicks through a couple pages and arrives at the Get Started page, where they will indicate the number of items they are ordering:

The page can be found at /pages/getting-started

This page works well on desktop and most mobile devices. Here's what it looks like on iOS8: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wa59cyz3i6plyf9/IMG_6241.JPG?dl=0

However, on iOS7, there is a bug and everything outside the logo does not load (regardless of browser): https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwtel5oktrhccqx/IMG_6242.JPG?dl=0

I have no idea what is causing this bug or how to fix it. There isn't a way, as far as I know, to create a special version of this page for iOS7 users.

Does anyone know what direction to head in or can provide guidance?

Thank you so much!

EDIT: I added a response with pictures in the comments

Comment: what about showing the code? you provide a lot of data, but nothing is useful. You can plug the iphone to the computer and inspect the page with safari

Comment: seems cache issue. better share code.

Comment: Thanks guys, do these screenshots help? https://www.dropbox.com/s/08ypm83ad9q4mfc/Screenshot%202015-04-07%2012.26.20.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ms81coguwyc0qe7/Screenshot%202015-04-07%2012.26.39.png?dl=0

Comment: We solved the problem, there was a background image of black being used that wasn't loading on ios7. We just changed it to a black color background instead. Thanks for the help!